Web version of my Flutter app does not compile
I recently wanted to to port my app to Web, but I believe plugin flutter_archive is not supported.
So my questions are:

How to exclude the plugin from the dependences when building for Web?
How to conditionally import a plugin for a given platform?

The build logs:
flutter build web

Target dart2js failed: ProcessException: Process exited abnormally with exit code 1:
../../../../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_platform_interface-2.4.4/lib/src/types/picked_file/html.dart:30:38:
Error: The method 'UnmodifiableUint8ListView' isn't defined for the class 'PickedFile'.
 - 'PickedFile' is from 'package:image_picker_platform_interface/src/types/picked_file/html.dart'
 ('../../../../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_platform_interface-2.4.4/lib/src/types/picked_file/html.dart').
      return Future<Uint8List>.value(UnmodifiableUint8ListView(_initBytes!));
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/archive-3.3.0/lib/src/bzip2/bzip2.dart:5:7:
Error: Method not found: 'UnmodifiableUint8ListView'.
      UnmodifiableUint8ListView(Uint8List(0));
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/archive-3.3.0/lib/src/bzip2/bzip2.dart:7:7:
Error: Method not found: 'UnmodifiableUint32ListView'.
      UnmodifiableUint32ListView(Uint32List(0));
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/archive-3.3.0/lib/src/bzip2/bzip2.dart:9:7:
Error: Method not found: 'UnmodifiableInt32ListView'.
      UnmodifiableInt32ListView(Int32List(0));
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: Compilation failed.
  Command: /Users/stephanedeluca/development/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart --disable-dart-dev /Users/stephanedeluca/development/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/snapshots/dart2js.dart.snapshot
  --platform-binaries=/Users/stephanedeluca/development/flutter/bin/cache/flutter_web_sdk/kernel --invoker=flutter_tool -Ddart.vm.product=true -DFLUTTER_WEB_AUTO_DETECT=false
  -DFLUTTER_WEB_USE_SKIA=true -DFLUTTER_WEB_CANVASKIT_URL=https://www.gstatic.com/flutter-canvaskit/c9b9d5780da342eb3f0f5e439a7db06f7d112575/ --native-null-assertions --no-source-maps -o
  /Users/stephanedeluca/Documents/dsei/Clients/2014 ALADDIN SAS/Projets/Carburant Discount/flutter/carburantdiscount/.dart_tool/flutter_build/5a39e6ce629b58664072718a440a0c0c/app.dill
  --packages=.dart_tool/package_config.json --cfe-only /Users/stephanedeluca/Documents/dsei/Clients/2014 ALADDIN SAS/Projets/Carburant
  Discount/flutter/carburantdiscount/.dart_tool/flutter_build/5a39e6ce629b58664072718a440a0c0c/main.dart


Well I do not really answer the questions, but I migrated to archive, replacing flutter_archive.
With archive, Web being supported, I can keep on working on my project.
